# Android: Physical distance between 2 touch positions

Tags: android

In my app, the user will put 2 fingers on the screen. I want to calculate the distance between those 2 touch points in centimeters. Currently, I'm able to calculate the distance using x and y values provided in `onTouchEvent`. But that distance is not physical distance. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your calculated pixel distances `x` and `y` you can use the following to return distance in inches:

```
public double getScreenDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double xDist = Math.pow(Math.abs(x1 - x2) / dm.xdpi, 2);
    double yDist = Math.pow(Math.abs(y1 - y2) / dm.ydpi, 2);
    return Math.sqrt(xDist + yDist);
}
```

Then to convert to centimeters just multiply by 2.54.

Comment: You mean `return Math.sqrt(xDist + yDist);`?

Comment: Can you please explain the parameters of your function? I'm confused.

Comment: I have calculated distance between 2 pixel points. That distance is a single value. But this function takes 2 arguments.

Comment: Sure I was using x and y as distance diffs. I can modify to take in two points.

Comment: And to clarify, you can't calculate the distance in pixels first and then convert because there are different densities in the x and y directions.

Comment: Got it. Let me test the function and will get back to you :)

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks a lot :)